# Android (Automotive) S/T/U Shared storage between users

Tags: android, android-automotive

I am looking for a way on how and where I can put and edit files that are accessible independently of the currently active android user.

I am working on Android Automotive but I think this does not matter.

Why would I want this?
Imagine a big database that is shared across users.

Android explicitly mentions the BlobStoreManager but it is unclear to me how the data can then be shared between users.

Comment: Are you developing a system app, or just a normal 3rd party app that the user would get off the play store?

Comment: A system app with privilieged permissions

Comment: I don't know if there's a more "official" way to share data across users these days that doesn't involve a web server, but one option is to utilize the system user 0 that is always running in the background. A service running in user 0 can be bound to from the foreground user allowing you to use user 0's storage for your db.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use `/sdcard/Android/obb`. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690667/2110188).

Comment: this used to work but is no longer